# Getting errors while compiling Irrlicht for Android

Tags: android, irrlicht

I was trying to compile the Irrlicht port for Android but I continue getting errors while following [these instructions](http://gitorious.org/irrlichtandroid/pages/Home).

I created a jni folder inside my project folder and the contents looked like this,

```
PROJECT/jni/Application.mk
PROJECT/jni/l.sh
PROJECT/jni/MakeAndroid.py
```

Then I went into the console and navigated to the PROJECT/jni/project/jni folder. From there I typed "ndk-build" and I got the following errors,

```
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= importgl.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= app-android.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= android-activity.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= android-receiver.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CIrrDeviceAndroid.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CVideoModeList.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CFPSCounter.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CNullDriver.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= COGLESDriver.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= COGLESTexture.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= COGLESExtensionHandler.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CColorConverter.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CImage.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CImageLoaderBMP.cpp 
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CImageLoaderJPG.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CImageLoaderPCX.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CImageLoaderPNG.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CImageLoaderPSD.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CImageLoaderTGA.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CImageLoaderPPM.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CImageLoaderWAL.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CImageLoaderRGB.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CImageWriterBMP.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CImageWriterJPG.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CImageWriterPCX.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CImageWriterPNG.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CImageWriterPPM.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CImageWriterPSD.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= CImageWriterTGA.cpp
Compile++ arm    : irrlicht <= COGLES2Driver.cpp
In file included from /home/cmetrolis/NetBeansProjects/MyProject/jni/project/jni/COGLES2Driver.h:44,
         from /home/cmetrolis/NetBeansProjects/MyProject/jni/project/jni/COGLES2Driver.cpp:6:
/home/cmetrolis/NetBeansProjects/MyProject/jni/project/jni/COGLES2ExtensionHandler.h:18:23: error: GLES2/gl2.h: No such file or directory
```

I cut out a ton of the errors after this, but they mostly all say "No such file or directory". Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the Application.mk, you need at least android platform 2.0 for OGLES 2.0. In your application.mk, add this line:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-6
```

Look at the project/default.properties:

```
target=android-8
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Ellis. Should I add this to all Android.mk files? Or just the top most level one? Because there is one under PROJECT/jni/ and one under PROJECT/jni/project/jni

Comment: PROJECT/jni/Application.mk

Comment: Adding APP_PLATFORM := android-6 to the Android.mk file did not fix it. I am still getting an error at the same place.

Comment: look into the default.properties and add target=android-8